Existence of Primitive root modulo $m^2-1$
Here's my question:

For which $m\in \mathbb{N}$ does there exists a primitive root mod $m^2-1$?

My approach: We know that primitive root mod $n$ exists if $n= 1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$ where $p$ is odd primes.
But clearly 1,2,4 $\neq m^2-1 , \forall m\in \mathbb{N}$
Now we left with two cases
Case-1:
$m^2-1=2p^k$ for some $k>0$,
Then $(m+1)(m-1)=2p^k$ which is even,
so $m$ is odd.
Then $4|(m+1)(m-1)$ but $4 \nmid 2p^k$ ,
Hence contradiction!
Is it correct? And what about the other case when $m^2-1=p^k$ for some $k$? I don't know how to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Hint:  If $(m+1)(m-1)=p^k$ then both $(m+1)$ and $(m-1)$ must be powers of $p$.  But $\gcd(m-1,m+1)≤2$.

@lulu Fine. Got it.
